# Why did Rep. Omar conclude her criticism of US troops with the phrase "NotTodaySatan"?

Tags: united-states, somalia

Putting aside whether or not Omar was truthful when she [tweeted](https://twitter.com/IlhanMN/status/919736859584090113):

> ...the thousands of Somalis killed by the American forces that day

(in reference to the October 1993 Battle of Mogadishu)

Why did she conclude her criticism of US troops with the hashtag "#NotTodaySatan"?

Comment: It looks like a contemporaneous meme given that the tweet was from 2017.  There are multiple reads of what she could be saying though.

Comment: Where does the "_her criticism of US troops_" in the title come from? The tweet you link is concerned with correcting an incredibly racist statement. I don't see how it makes any special effort to criticize US troops. It does state that US troops kill people - but as an answer to somebody implying they didn't, you can hardly consider that "criticism".

Comment: @R.Schmitz I think it's clear that she is criticizing the number of Somalis killed.  Whether she blames Clinton, or the troops actually in Somalia, or the chain of command somewhere in between, I don't know.

Comment: @DavePhD With all due respect, no it's not. Just saying "US troops kill so-and-so many people" is not criticism, it's a statistic. Now, "killing people" is not a good thing, but if somebody says "_they killed 12 people_" and I say "_no, it was 14_", then that's not criticism. We can consider the perspective that this one tweet is part of a bigger narrative... but then she didn't "conclude" _that_ with NotTodaySatan.

Comment: @R.Schmitz Yes, it's part of a bigger narrative.  People were talking about the number of Somalis killed by terrorism, and she implies that the killing of thousands of Somalis by Clinton that day was the worst act of terrorism.  And then she invokes Satan.

Comment: @DavePhD "_Yes, it's part of a bigger narrative._" which isn't "concluded" with #NotTodaySatan - that's _my point_ for this perspective.

Answer (score 40):

"Not Today Satan" is a common phrase used by religious people that means "I'm not going to brought down today". While there is clearly an effort to make it out as if Rep. Omar is saying that America is Satan, that is clearly not what this phrase means.

If you look for [other tweets that use that hashtag](https://twitter.com/hashtag/NotTodaySatan?src=hash), once you scroll down past the manufactured right-wing outrage, you'll see tweets like:

> work drags lol #nottodaysatan
>
> Almost accidentally read an Endgame spoiler #NOTTODAYSATAN
>
> When life isn't the way you hoped, you change it and make it what you need. Work is hard, but providing for myself and my husband is more important than the trivial bitches. #nottodaysatan pic.twitter.com/3i39KznNIW
>
> when I was 14 they predicted a valve replacement at 30. Today was my annual check up, and a bitch gets to keep her valve! What’s good heart disease!? #nottodaysatan
>
> Already know some type of blessing is on the way when the energy vampire ex pops up. Demons can smell happiness. #Nottodaysatan ‍♀️

No Anti-American sentiment there!

Some more evidence that this is not some sort of secret terrorist hashtag:

- From CBN News (The Christian Perspective): ['Not Today Satan': How to Respond to Hollywood Haters and Their War on Christians](http://www1.cbn.com/cbnnews/entertainment/2017/april/hollywood-haters-how-christians-should-respond-to-their-war-on-faith)
- From *Boundless* a "Focus on the Family community for Christian young adults": [Not Today, Satan: Battling the Enemy’s Lies](https://www.boundless.org/blog/not-today-satan-battling-the-enemys-lies/)
- A "Not Today Satan" shirt from [ChristianBook.com](https://www.christianbook.com/not-today-satan-shirt-black-large/pd/29403L) with the "Witness message":  "Not Today Satan. Submit Yourselves Therefore To God. Resist The Devil, And He Will flee From You. James 4:7."
- A ["Not Today Satan" Lanyard](https://www.lifeway.com/en/product/not-today-satan-lanyard-P005814324) from LifeWay Christian Resources
- Etsy, not known as hotbed for Islamist Extremism,  has [3284 items with that slogan on it](https://www.etsy.com/market/not_today_satan), often paired with a cross.
- Urban Dictionary attributes its mainstream popularity to [Bianca Del Rio, the winner of Season 6 of RuPaul's Drag Race](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Not%20today%20Satan%2C%20not%20today.)
- There are even [memes that use it](https://www.google.com/search?q=not+today+satan+meme&client=safari&rls=en&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiqzITKlOzhAhVpc98KHUtjAEUQ_AUIDigB)

---

As for why she might have said that, the tweet you linked to is a **direct** reply to another [tweet by @j_w_84](https://twitter.com/RonHarrisMN/status/919712455491772416) which I've reproduced below:

[image]

In that tweet, Joshua claims that the that the worst terrorist attack in Somalia was the Battle of Mogadishu where 19 Americans were killed, not the then recent terrorist attack (referenced in the original tweet by Al Franken) where 230 Somalis were killed. The only way that makes sense is if you completely devalue the lives of Somalis, both those killed in the recent terrorist attack (to say that 19 dead is worse than 230 dead) and those killed in the fighting in Mogadishu (U.S. special representative to Somalia Robert B. Oakley estimated that there were [1500-2000 civilian casualties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_Mogadishu_(1993)#Somalia) due to the reality of fighting a pitched battle in a crowded city).

It's this casually racist attitude from Joshua, which holds that only American lives matter, that Rep. Omar is referring to: just like heart disease, boring work, or Avengers spoilers, the racist attitudes of some will not bring her down and stop the important work of fighting against it.

Comment: *'is a common phrase'* are you sure about that? It doesn't show up in Google's Ngram and it's listed by Urban Dictionary as a [quote from someone on RuPaul's Drag Race](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Not%20today%20Satan%2C%20not%20today.). Do you have references of its use prior to that show?

Comment: @JJJ I'm amazed I can't find any more detail, but at least anecdotally I can say I've heard that phrase often enough as far back as between 2008-2012

Comment: What I've been able to find is that it appears to be mainly used by Christians before the show, only entering secular culture after the show.

Comment: Its seem even more curious to classify the (1993) Battle of Mogadishu as a "terrorist attack" in the first place, since it appears that the US forces (with allies) were the ones attacking. I can imagine some people being ready to call the US "terrorists", but not the same people that would count only US casualties. And if it _was_ a terrorist attack then surely 1500-2000 is more than 230 ...

Comment: @JJJ The 1999 movie Toy Story 2 contains a reference to this phrase ('Not today, Zurg') and the 1994 movie Ace Ventura contains it verbatim - it's old and well established, I'd say.

Comment: @samiles are you sure? I cannot find it in the [transcript of the latter](https://www.springfieldspringfield.co.uk/movie_script.php?movie=ace-ventura-pet-detective). As for the first, that obviously lacks the reference to satan. ;)

Comment: @JJJ The Toy Story quote definitely refers to that phrase, IMO, as I said, "references". And you're quite right about Ace Ventura, I was muddled with something else. There's numerous uses of it long before the Ru Paul suggestion above.

Comment: @samiles yea, there probably are. Maybe a fun question for ELU?

Comment: @divibisan So you don't think there is a contrast being made between "that day" and "today"?  In the original tweet, "that day" is immediately followed by "NotToday".

Answer (score 7):

Probably as a humorous way of saying "you're not going to get one past me."

This seems to be a recent but widespread phrase. We can see [many humorous books](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=Not+today+satan#ip=1) with this phrase in their title.

The original use was seemingly literal, mainly coming from Christians metaphorically telling Satan that he wouldn't win.

> When the computers act up I speak "In the name of Jesus not today Satan.
>
> <sub>*My Book is My Story: Surrendering My Journey to the Holy Spirit* (2013)</sub>

Or

> When I sense him using my rough day to steal my joy, he's crossing a line and I tell him "Not today, Satan." I even have T-shirt that says it in big, white, block letters.
>
> <sub>*The Year of Living Happy: Finding Contentment and Connection in a Crazy World* (2018)</sub>

However, it seems to have mutated due to overuse (e.g., people would say "Not today, Satan" when their computers acted up or they were having a bad day). While the original phrase referenced actually catching Satan trying to ruin one's life and refusing to allow this, the broad version seems to refer to catching anyone in the act and refusing to allow them to go forward, particularly in relation to not letting someone ruin one's day.

Comment: was "not today Satan" still associated with Christians when she tweeted this, or had it already become secularized?

Comment: Check the other answer, but I'd say it had broad secular usage. Christians have still continued to use it in the Christian usage until the present day, though.